# Output printed multiple times even after adding break

Tags: python

So in this part of the code im writing, the program keeps printing the output multiple times in the else statment. I tried to add the break but it´s still printing 6 times. What is the problem? Im new to python btw :)
Here is the code:

```
for Path in mapp:
if Path.is_file():
    with Path.open("r") as file:
        try:
            for line in file.readlines():
                if keyword in line:
                    keyword_files.append(str(Path))
                    Hittad = open("spara.txt", "a")
                    Hittad.write("Sökord hittad i:" + str(Path) + "\n")
                    Hittad.close()
                    print("Sökord hittad i:", "\n", str(Path))
                else:
                    Intehittad = open("Intehittad.txt", "a")
                    Intehittad.writelines("Finns ej" + "\n")
                    Intehittad.close()
                    print("Inte hittad")
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: `break` breaks out of the inner loop `for line in file.readlines()`. The outer loop `for Path in mapp` continues running

Comment: Tjenare! Welcome to SO! A bit uncertain what you mean should happen here. Try adding what you intend to achieve with the program. You only tell us what you mean is wrong, not what is right :-)

Comment: Very short, this program takes two inputs, 1 path and 1 keyword. The program will then search for this keyword in the path and print in which files it found it in. Everything works fine except this last part, which is that the loop keeps printing the output mulitple times. as @Forcebru mentioned, it only breaks the inner loop, but when i break the outer loop i get an error

Comment: Update: @ForceBru, thank you! I wrote the try and except outside the loop and then the break in the outer loop. That didnt give me any errors :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To break out of both for loops try one of:

- Split the for-loops into a separate function and `return` out of it
- Use for-else construct to detect when inner loop used `break` and then `break` out of outer loop
- raise an `Exception` in the inner loop and catch it outside the outer loop

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to investigate this kind of issues is to use Debug Mode in your IDE (personally I use PyCharm). I think that in your case printed output is valid and is a consequence of nested for loops.

Comment: Thank you, solved the issue :)